# pytesseract does not recognize the character in the image

Tags: python-3.x, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to use `pytesseract` but when I supply the image it doesn't recognize it. Is it because the image is small? if yes what should the minimum size be? Is it suitable for recognizing single characters segmented from an image?

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

image = Image.open(path)
num = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
print(num)
```

This is the image:
[image]

Comment: What gets printed?

Comment: @Acccumulation nothing!

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass additional parameter ***config*** to the ***image_to_string*** method with following value:

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(filename, config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
```